# Какой знак препинания нужен в предложении и требуются ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале (?) "все лгут".

Answer (score 1):

Вводные предложения, присоединяемые союзными словами или союзами, чаще всего выделяются **запятой**:

***Мне помогал маляр, или, как он сам называл себя, подрядчик малярных работ (Ч.)***

Посредством **тире** простые по структуре вводные предложения выделяются редко; обычно с помощью тире выделяются более распространенные вводные предложения:

***Дать противнику уйти, или — как это говорится на торжественном языке воинских уставов — дать ему оторваться — это для разведчиков крупная неприятность (Каз.)***

Кавычки в таких предложениях обычно не используются, несмотря на наличие в вводных конструкциях слов "говорится", "называл".

Ваше предложение можно оформить с запятой и без квычек:

***Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале, все лгут.***

Также возможен вариант с кавычками, хотя мне они кажутся излишними:

***Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале, "все лгут".***

Допустимо и тире, так как вводное предложение достаточно распространено:

***Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале — все лгут.***

Answer (score 0):

**Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале ― все лгут.**

Обособляем вводное предложение тире в связи с наличием увеличенной паузы, запятой здесь недостаточно.

Кавычки можно не ставить, если мы не подчеркиваем дословность выражения.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, "все лгут" - это не название сериала. это слова, которые говорил доктор хаус.

Comment: Ну если доктор так говорил, то ответ меняем.

Comment: а можно чуть обнаглеть и попросить оставить оба варианта? а главное - как передать на письме что имелось в виду - цитата или название сериала (если бы такой был)?

Comment: Можно вводное предложение продлить Как говорилось в одном популярном сериале "Все лгут".... Или: Так говорилось в одном популярном сериале "Все лгут".

Comment: Это не название сериала, а цитата из него.

Comment: Я ответила с учетом того, что  это не название сериала, а цитата из него. .